# Serenity BDD cucumber - is there a way in serenity to avoid over writing the report folder?

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

Currently when the report is generated it overwrites the reports folder of previous run. Is it possible to specify folder to have timestamp in name by passing something like this?

> serenity.outputDirectory=reports\&Now()  in serenity properties file..

I can write code which will move the files whatever there in reports file to newly generated directory during runtime. The challenge here is, we don’t know the point where the reports are getting generated.

Comment: Are you running your tests off of an enclosing application, perhaps Jenkins? If so, you are able to setup a pre-build step to override `serenity.outputDirectory` property. If not, I would write a short script to override (based on the current time stamp) it and run it first in batch with your test framework. Another possibility is to either set in in your @Before or @After methods, however, this sounds like bad practice.

Comment: I'm not using Jenkins. JD -regarding this, I would write a short script to override (based on the current time stamp) it and run it first in batch with your test framework.. my tests are in Given , Then gherkin format. so where do you suggest to put the code to override serenity.outputDirectory . Also can you please give line of code which we can use to override serenity.outputDirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a simpler and faster solution for you. No need for coding either. This is what you do:

*I'm using Windows Command Line / .BAT file and Maven for this.*

In CMD, create your own time stamp variable, such as:

`set mytimestamp=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%`

then

`echo %mytimestamp%`

output should be something like this

`20162710_122305`

Make sure not to include "/" or white spaces with your format. These can cause unexpected folder hierarchy, which will most probably cause your build to fail.

To pass this to your `serenity.outputDirectory` just do (in Maven)

`mvn test -Dserenity.outputDirectory=target/site/report_%mytimestamp%`

and this is what you get

[image: output folders]

*NOTE that if you run `mvn clean` it will wipe all your reports. Also, this does not permanently overwrite your project's `serenity.outputDirectory` property. If you were to NOT use `-Dserenity.outputDirectory=target/site/report_%mytimestamp%` the property will default to whatever value you have in your project.

This is what a .BAT file would look like

```
set mytimestamp=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
call mvn test -Dserenity.outputDirectory=target/site/report_%mytimestamp%
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked perfectly :) im using gradle so changed the command in BAT file accordingly as follows                                                                                                     set mytimestamp=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

.\gradlew.bat test -Dserenity.outputDirectory=reports/report_%mytimestamp% aggregate